# RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager with images loading from Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide, staggered-gridview, staggeredgridlayout

I am having a problem showing `RecyclerView` with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` whose item contain an `imageview` and the image is loaded in `imageview` using `glide`.
The problem i am facing is that after images getting loaded they are not staggered and are of equal sizes as well there is a big gap between two columns. How to vary the height of images with no gaps in columns?

Comment: If there's a big gap between the columns then you should also provide `scaleType` to your images, I would suggest you set either centerCrop or fitXY scaleType.

Comment: giving any image +  code of your work would be more understable

Comment: You can have a look at this where u can use glide with 
[Glide/Picasso-RecyclerView-StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://github.com/yuvaraj119/Picasso-RecyclerView-StaggeredGridLayoutManager)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally i am able to find out the soultion. I had to create the custom imageview to vary its aspect ratio in Staggered Recycler View.

```
public class DynamicHeightNetworkImageView extends ImageView {
private float mAspectRatio = 1.5f;

public DynamicHeightNetworkImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public DynamicHeightNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public DynamicHeightNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public void setAspectRatio(float aspectRatio) {
    mAspectRatio = aspectRatio;
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, (int) (measuredWidth / mAspectRatio));
}
}
```

Then in onBindViewHolder of the adapter i set the aspect ratio of the image by -

```
Picasso.with(this).load(THUMB_URL).into(holder.thumbnailView);
holder.thumbnailView.setAspectRatio(ASPECT_RATIO));
```

Comment: thank you.. 2 years later, you still save my project & my life :D

Comment: what to pass ASPECT_RATIO? how to get it?

Answer (score 14):

I was having the same issue. What worked for me was to set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` for my ImageView. I'm not even setting scaleType.

Here's the full content of my layout file, item.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gif_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorFiller"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to the ImageView in the item layout and use `CenterCrop` and `FitCenter` in Glide like this:

```
Glide.with(vh.view.getContext())
        .load(item.getUrl())
        .centerCrop()
        .fitCenter()
        .thumbnail(0.3f)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.img_placeholder)
        .into(vh.image);
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Intialize Your RecyclerView**

```
 RecyclerView recyclerGallery = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.gallery_recycler_view);
 gaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, 1);
 recyclerGallery.setLayoutManager(gaggeredGridLayoutManager);
 galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdaptor(ProfImageGallery.this, imgsUrl);
 recyclerGallery.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
```

**Then Your Adaptor ( Edit According to your Need)**

```
  public class GalleryAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdaptor.ViewHolder> {

        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<String> mDataset;


  // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
        public GalleryAdaptor(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mdataList) {
              this.mContext = mContext;
              this.mDataset = mdataList;
        }

        // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public GalleryAdaptor.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

              // create a new view
              View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                             .inflate(R.layout.row_gallery, parent, false);

              // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters 
              ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
              return vh;
        }

        // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
              // - get element from your dataset at this position
              // - replace the contents of the view with that element


              String imageUrl = mDataset.get(position);

              holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 

              //load the image url with a callback to a callback method/class

              Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .into(holder.workImage, 
                          new ImageLoadedCallback(holder.progressBar) {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                      if (holder.progressBar != null) {
                                            holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                      }
                                }
                          });
        }
```

**Replace Picaso Code i.e**

```
  Picasso.with(mContext)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .into(holder.workImage, 
              new ImageLoadedCallback(holder.progressBar) {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                          if (holder.progressBar != null) {
                                holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                          }
                    }
              });
```

**With Glide.**

```
  Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```

Comment: what is the layout for R.layout.row_gallery ?

Comment: this is the row for your layout used in recycler view

Answer (score 0):

For me it's working

```js
        Picasso.get()
                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                .config(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .into(holder.imageView);
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/id_imgItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/id_imgItemGets"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```